# php - CLI and custom commands

Tags: php

I'm currently trying to make a php script that can be interactive with the user by executing commands. The user have to use the script in the Terminal.

here is an example about what I'm talking about:

```
>php robot.php
>Hello, I'm the GoodRobot number 8731039139, nice to meet you!
>Please type a command below:
>say "Hello" **// user types this**
>GoodRobot no 8731039139: Hello **// robot.php outputs this**
```

I want it to make it interactive as soon as init() is called but I've been trying to do what you can see below and it doesn't seem to work.

Here is my full code

```
<?php

class Robot 
{
    // ?? \\
}

class GoodRobot extends Robot
{
    static protected $serialNumber; 

    private $name;
    private $type = "Droid";

    public function __construct($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        echo "Hello, I'm the GoodRobot number " . self::$serialNumber . ", nice to meet you!\n";
    }

    public function init()
    {
        echo "Please type a command below:" . PHP_EOL;
        $handle = fopen ("php://stdin","r");
        $line = fgets($handle);
        if(trim($line) != 'say')
        {
            print(say($str));
        }
        elseif (trim($line) != 'help') {
            print(help());
        }
        else
        {
            echo "ERROR: Unknown command. Type \"help\" if you need help." . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }

    public function setName($name) 
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getName($name)
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function help()
    {
        echo "Here is a list of commands: \n - say \"something\" \n - shutDown \n";
    }

    public function say($str)
    {
        echo "GoodRobot no " . self::$serialNumber . " : " . $str . "\n";
    }

    public function turnOn()
    {
        echo "Waking up... Please be patient.\n";
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function shutDown()
    {
        echo "Shutting down...\n";
        exit;
    }
}

$hi = new GoodRobot("hi");
$hi -> init();
```

When I'm trying to "say"

It display a fatal error

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function say()

Comment: what IS happening?

Comment: somehow your function *say*     is executing?

Comment: @coder I edited my code to be more clear

Comment: its working then. but  it should be `$this->say($whatever)`

Comment: @delboy1978uk echo $this->say($str); doesn't recognize $str

Comment: you don't define $str. did you mean $line?

Comment: try `$this->say($line);`

Comment: @delboy1978uk Doesn't detect the string on the say function

Comment: `var_dump($line); exit;` before the if statement in `init()` and see what it picks up

Comment: @delboy1978uk still says $str unknown

Comment: you do not anywhere in init say `$str = ` something, so of course it will complain. You only have $handle and $line

Comment: @delboy1978uk How do I add $str?

Comment: you don't, you pass $line, as thats what you called it

Comment: if I execute say "something" it doesn't execute the command and doesn't recognize it

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `$this->` when referring to a method in the current class.  I've also changed your input to just `readline()` as this handles the IO.

Also note the string manipulation to change the `say "Hello"` to remove the first bit and any surrounding quotes.

```
public function init()
{
    echo "Please type a command below:" . PHP_EOL;
    $line = readline();
    if(substr($line, 0, 3) == 'say')
    {
        $line = substr($line, 3);
        $line = rtrim(trim($line,"\" "),"\" \n\r");
        $this->say($line);
    }
    elseif (substr($line, 0, 4) == 'help') {
        $this->help();
    }
    else
    {
        echo "ERROR: Unknown command. Type \"help\" if you need help." . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure why you had `print()` around the `say()` call, `say()` echos out the string, so the print is not needed.

You also need to check the first 3 chars are 'say' rather than using `trim()`.  Same for 'help' (although 4 chars this time).

**Update:**
When testing add..

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

to the top of your script, it helps in showing any errors in the code.

Comment: It outputs a "e" whatever I do, weird

Comment: say "something" doesn't do anything it just displays the say function without any string and just blank space

Comment: just typing say displays an e

Comment: OK - can't replicate that.  I'm assuming you've made no changes to any of the other code in your original question.

Comment: Also - worth adding the lines I've added to the answer - they show any errors in your code when testing.